# Combining object and property

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have 3 tables.

First table name: **Objects**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ahmet |
| 2 | Hasan |

Second table name: **Properties**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | EyeColor |
| 2 | Height |

Third table name: **Data**

| ObjectID | PropertyID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Blue |
| 1 | 2 | 1.70 |
| 2 | 1 | Green |
| 2 | 2 | 1.90 |

Using the above three tables, I want to create the following list with SQL.

| Name | EyeColor | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ahmet | Blue | 1.70 |
| Hasan | Green | 1.90 |

I tried this transmission as sample SQL

```
SELECT Distinct Objects.Name, (SELECT * FROM Datas where PropertyID = Datas.PropertyID )
FROM Datas
INNER JOIN Objects ON Datas.ObjectID = Objects.ID
INNER JOIN Properties ON Datas.PropertyID = Properties.ID
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm new here, sorry for the deficiency.

Comment: I recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you @DaleK, I'll work on this

Comment: And specifically for [asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Thank you, can you help me my question ?

Comment: I've been dealing with this problem for hours. I made a lot of effort myself, but I could not, so I wanted to ask here.

Comment: I was afraid to add, because I think this is far from the truth. I added

Comment: Your views are very valuable to me, thank you very much for your information. @DaleK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from the table that has the rows you want in your final result i.e. `Objects` (although I would strongly recommend never using this as a user table name since its also a system table name).

Then join on the information you need for your other columns.

I highly recommend the use of table aliases to make your query easier to read and understand.

```
select [Name], E.[Value] EyeColor, H.[Value] Height
from dbo.[Objects] O
inner join dbo.[Data] H on H.ObjectID = O.id
    and H.PropertyID = (select P.id from dbo.Properties P where P.[Name] = 'Height')
inner join dbo.[Data] E on E.ObjectID = O.id
    and E.PropertyID = (select P.id from dbo.Properties P where P.[Name] = 'EyeColor');
```

Answer (score 0):

I will help you to figure how to solve this problem for now but you need to see a SQL tutorials,

So first of all you need in the O/P you want to select both `EyeColor` and `Height` for the person so how can you figure out that this value is for the specific person you need to check for that.

It will be a query like this:

```
SELECT Objects.Name AS NAME, EyeColor.Value AS EyeColor, Height.Value AS Height  
FROM Objects AS Obj  
INNER JOIN Data AS EyeColor ON EyeColor.ObjectID = Obj.ID  
AND EyeColor.PropertyID = 1  
INNER JOIN Data AS Height ON Height.ObjectID = Obj.ID  
AND Height.PropertyID = 2;
```

**You need to test it and modify it.**

Note that: there are a lot of other solution so always try to figure what you want well first and then start divide the problem and then try to start writing your query.

Check @Dale K solution too at the same question as it can help you a lot.

Comment: @DaleK you are totally right, I just wanted to show him a quick example only, thanks a lot for editing it.

Comment: @DaleK you are right, I will take care in the next answers and comments, Thanks again for your efforts and for your advice. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments. @MohamedBdr

Comment: @MertAktürk Thank you

Comment: @DaleK I modified it Thanks alot for your support again.

Comment: @DaleK Done again :) thank you really for your patient and your support.